# Switched to Xubuntu but Unity theme won't go away

Tags: xubuntu, ubuntu-11.10, ubuntu-unity

I got fed up with Unity and decided to switch to Xubuntu, following the instructions on [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/348027/can-i-make-ubuntu-11-10s-desktop-look-like-11-04s-ubuntu-classic). Almost everything went well, and I'm much happier with the system. However the window borders from the Unity theme are still being used, overriding the Xubuntu themes.

I've uninstalled all the Unity stuff that I can find. I have, however, kept Compiz for some of its functionality. I note that if I disable the "Window Decoration" plugin the whole border disappears leaving nothing behind.

I want to have normal Xubuntu borders. Note that applications like Chromium which handle their own borders display correctly.

*I'll gladly give more details, or upload screenshots. Just let me know what information would be helpful.*

Answer (score 1):

It is the windows manager (in your case Compiz) that draws the window borders. (It is possible for applications to request borderless windows, which is what Chromium does.) The default window manager for XFCE (and xubuntu) is XFWM4 which will probably have some other look by default. But you can of course continue to use Compiz if you want to. You just have to find some other theme for Compiz that matches your prefered XFCE theme better.